# React useState() - adding new element in array not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, socket.io

I am making chat app using React native and socket.io but when I receive a message I want to add to array of messages. But somehow its not working. It replaces the array elements instead of pushing/adding element to it.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
    const id = data.id
    receiveMessage(id)
}, []);

async function receiveMessage(id){
    await message.init(id)
    message.recieveMessage(message=>{
        setMessages([...messages, message])//something is wrong over here
    })
}


async function send(){
    if(text){
        message.sendMessage(text, data=>{
            setMessages([...messages, data])//this part works perfectly
        })
    }
    setText(null)
}
```

here is `Messages object`:

```
export class Message {
    private socket: Socket
    private room: string
    constructor(socketio: Socket){
        this.socket = socketio
        this.room = null
    }
    async init(id: string){
        if(id === this.room) {
            return
        }
        this.room = id
        this.socket.emit("join", {id: id, session: await getSessionToken()})
        
        const prom = new Promise((res, rej)=>{
            this.socket.on("joined", message=>{
                res("done")
            })
        })
        await prom
        return "done"
    }
    public sendMessage(message: string, callback){
        const socket = this.socket
        socket.emit("message", message)
        socket.on("sent", callback)
    }
    public recieveMessage(callback){
        const socket = this.socket
        socket.on("receive message", callback)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible it's because you're not passing the previous state to the `setMessages` call?

Maybe give something like this a shot instead

```
async function receiveMessage(id) {
  await message.init(id)

  message.recieveMessage(message => {
    setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, message])
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But i didnt understand the difference between 
`setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, message])` and
`setMessages([...messages, message])

`

Comment: @BilljeshBaidya Functional state update, it updates from the previous state whereas the regular update is grabbing whatever closed over value of `messages` was when the callback was created.